# polkitd: unrecognized service [Ubuntu Server 16.04.3]

Tags: policykit

Running `sudo service polkitd reload` gives me a `polkitd: unrecognized service` message. I restarted the `dbus` service, the message remained the same. I thought `polkit` is supposed to be part of the system, so I don't know how to deal with this issue.

Comment: 16.04 should be using `systemctl` - what does `systemctl list-unit-files | grep polkit` say?

Comment: `polkitd.service                    static`

Comment: and `systemctl status polkitd.service`?

Comment: `● polkitd.service - Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/polkitd.service; static; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since xxx
 Main PID: 1136 (polkitd)
    Tasks: 3
   Memory: 2.8M
      CPU: 19ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/polkitd.service
           └─1136 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug

Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to
Ubuntu polkitd[1136]: started daemon version 0.105 using authori
Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to R
lines 1-13/13 (END)`

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `systemctl restart polkitd.service`